# How a heatmap is overlaid by another one, by calling matplotlib imshow twice for the same ax?

Tags: image, matplotlib

An exciting animation was posted on twitter recently: https://twitter.com/thomas_rackow/status/1392509885883944960.
One of the authors explained in this Jupyter Notebook https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/koldunovn/FESOM_SST_shaded_by_U/blob/main/FESOM_SST_shaded_by_U.ipynb
how a frame is created.

Related to the simple code displayed by this notebook, my question is: when we call `imshow` twice for the same `ax`:

```
ax.imshow(np.flipud(sst.sst.values), cmap=cm.RdBu_r,  vmin=12, vmax=24)
ax.imshow(np.flipud(u.u_surf.values), alpha=0.3, cmap=cm.gray, vmin=-.3, vmax=0.3)
```

what operations performs matplotlib, behind the scenes, to get a layered image?
I worked with alpha blending in Open CV - Python, but here it starts with two arrays of the same shape (1000, 1000), and via `ax.imshow`, called twice for the two arrays, it  displays the resulting image.  I'd like to know how is it possible. What  arithmetic  operations  between images are involved?
I searched the matplotlib github repository to understand what's going on, but I couldn't find something relevant.

Comment: matplotlib uses a [Painter's_algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm): drawing each on top of the other.  Everywhere the values are 'NaN', the image will be transparent, so the lower layer stays visible. A very high resolution is needed to get a high quality. When there are more image points than visible pixels, these points get averaged to create an [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing) effect. Note that matplotlib's 3D rendering uses the same approach, causing many 3D limitations.

Comment: @JohanC   Thank you for your answer. I know the Painter' s algorithm, but I don't think that in this case it explains what color is assigned to each pixel of the output image. I suspect that an algorithm typical for images is involved here.

Comment: Well, additionally there is [color mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_mapping) which maps values to a color.  In this case probably a lot of experimentation was done to obtain interesting looking color combinations.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to illustrate that the two `imshow`(s) hide the alpha-blending of the two images.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

sst = xr.open_dataset('GF_FESOM2_testdata/sst.nc')
u = xr.open_dataset('GF_FESOM2_testdata/u_surf.nc')
v = xr.open_dataset('GF_FESOM2_testdata/v_surf.nc')

#Define the heatmap from SST-data and extract the array representing it as an image:

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1,
            constrained_layout=True,
            figsize=(10,  10))
f1 = ax1.imshow(np.flipud(sst.sst.values), cmap=cm.RdBu_r,  vmin=12, vmax=24)
ax1.axis('off');
arr1 = f1.make_image('notebook')[0] #array representing the above image

#Repeat the same procedure for  u-data set:

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(1, 1,
            constrained_layout=True,
            figsize=(10,  10))
f2 = ax2.imshow(np.flipud(u.u_surf.values),  cmap=cm.gray, vmin=-0.3, vmax=0.3)
ax2.axis('off');

arr2 = f2.make_image("notebook")[0]
#alpha blending of the two images amounts to a convex combination of the associated arrays
alpha1= 1  # background image alpha
alpha2 = 0.3  #foreground image alpha
arr = np.asarray((alpha2*arr2 + alpha1*(1-alpha2)*arr1)/(alpha2+alpha1*(1-alpha2)), dtype=np.uint8)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1,
            constrained_layout=True,
            figsize=(10,  10))
ax.imshow(np.flipud(arr))
ax.axis('off');
```